# Calculate $tr(T)$ where $T(x,y,z)=(3x-z,2x+4y+2z,-x+3z)$

Tags: linear-algebra

Calculate $tr(T)$ where $T(x,y,z)=(3x-z,2x+4y+2z,-x+3z)$

I don't know how to calculate the trace of a linear operator.

I know $tr(A)=a_{11}+...+a_{nn}$

Let $B=\{e_1,e_2,e_3\}$ a basis of $\mathbb{R}^3$ then $T_{BB}=\begin{bmatrix}
3 &2  &-1 \\ 
 0&4  &0 \\ 
-1&2  &3 
\end{bmatrix}$

My question:

> Is $tr(T_{BB})=tr(T)$ true? If not, how do I calculate the trace of a linear operator?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use standard vector to find trace,
$$T(1,0,0)=(3,2,-1)$$
$$T(0,1,0)=(0,4,0)$$
$$T(0,0,1)=(-1,2,3)$$
now trace of T is 3+4+3=10

Comment: let me know if it is not make sense

Comment: Then, the matrix associated to te transformation have the same trace of $T$. always this happen?

Comment: yes, you always can use a basis to find the matrix of T, for different basis you will get different matrix but trace never changed.

Answer (score 3):

Yes it is correct since trace is an invariant

$$T_{BB}=\begin{bmatrix}
3 &2  &-1 \\ 
 0&4  &0 \\ 
 -1&2  &3 
\end{bmatrix}\implies Tr(T)=10$$